# Is this set uncountable or countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove whether or not this set is countable: the functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(n)=0$ except for a finite number of $n \in \mathbb Z$.
I think this set is uncountable. So, if $f$ belongs to this set, there is an $n_0$ such that $f(n)=0$  $ \forall $ $n>n_0  $. I tried to prove that the set of functions for which this is true for a certain $n_0$ is uncountable but I'm having a hard time finding a function to do so...
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT** Find an injection from $\Bbb R$ into the set of functions by considering only functions which satisfy $g(n)=0$ for all $n\neq0$.

Comment: does this work: f from the set of functions which obtain a non zero value at n=0 to R. f(g)=g(0)?

Comment: Yes, it works just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an injection though, because even if the functions are different they can have the same value at 0.

Comment: (1) You can use a similar idea to define a surjection from the set of functions onto $\Bbb R$, that alone should suffice to prove the set is uncountable; (2) the injection is in the other direction, note that functions that have at most one nonzero element in their range at the point $0$ must be equal iff the agree on that element.

Comment: ok got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly, you could note that $\forall r\in\mathbb{R}$, the function that is $r$ at zero and 0 everywhere else is in the set. There are obviously uncountably many such functions.

Comment: The first word in your answer baffles me. How is this "alternatively" and not the same hint as mine? :-)

Comment: Because I totally failed to understand your hint D:

Comment: [It's because you didn't believe!](http://vuible.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/4142a6e69ff5220b0ec295a0290571cc.jpg)